# how to delete a string containing the symbol '/' from a file?

Tags: linux, centos

I need to delete the following string from a certain file:

```
Ba+/w+NWFlMa
```

I'm using the following command:

```
sed -i.bak '/Ba+/w+NWFlMa/d' /path/to/file
```

and getting the following error:

```
sed: couldn't open file +NWFlMa/d: No such file or directory
```

how can I fix this and make the '/' not to split the string?

**Important note:** this string is generated automatically and I'm invoking the command via Java code, so I don't know what will the string be the next time I'll run the code to delete it.

Comment: You need to escape the slash: ` sed -i .bak '/Ba+\/w+NWFlMa/d' /path/to/file`. The slash is obviously special to the search command.

Answer (score 0):

found the solution:

```
sed -i.bak '\|Ba+/w+NWFlMa|d' /path/to/file
```

Comment: You should accept your solution so the question shows as answered and accepted.